# Unable to compare two variables

Tags: php

I am reading an xml file using php, after reading those files i am accessing some values and comparing them here is the code for that:

```
$home = $match -> home -> name; 
$away = $match -> away -> name; 
$homescore = $match -> home -> shoots; 
$awayscore = $match -> away -> shoots;
if($home == 'Lakers' || $away == 'Lakers') {
    $played = $played+1;
    if($home == 'Lakers') {
        echo $homescore;
        echo $awayscore;
        if($homescore > $awayscore) {
            echo 'hi';
        }
    }
}
```

As it can be seen from the code above, i am reading in the name and shoots of a team. When i execute this the returned result is `63`. Now 6 is the `$homescore` 3 is the `$awayscore`. Based on these values i am expecting that it should also print `hi`. But for some reason i am not getting the desired output.

Anyone able to see if i am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps it's treating homescore and awayscore as strings. Why not cast them explicitly as integers?

Comment: How do you read the XML file? With `SimpleXML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your *'innest'* if statement with this code:

```
if((int)$homescore > (int)$awayscore)
    echo 'hi';
```